# How can heavy molecules slow down the rate of condensation?

Tags: magic, technology, economy

Mana is the background energy by which witches use to create magical spells. The level of mana content within the environment rises and falls with the passage of the tides, and consolidates in certain places more than it does in others. It is in these locations where condensation is likely to occur, which is the transformation of mana particles in the air into a liquid state. This can be done through magical rituals or specialized machines built to specifically for this purpose. The result is a visible substance which can serve as base ingredients in potions, power machinery, as well as other uses. This has led to a big industry of potion making and the combination of technology and arcana to create magitech. As such, it has become the lifeblood of society, gaining a place similar to oil. However, the amount of mana in the air at one time is limited, which makes the process of condensation expensive and difficult, similar to squeezing a wet rag for droplets of water. This supply must be naturally replenished on its own, which limits the amount of liquid that can be made at one time and the kind of spells that can be performed.

This scenario changes during a special time of day referred to as the "witching hour". This is a period of time in the morning in which mana particles in the environment increase many fold. This is the time when magic is strongest, and allows for the use of powerful spells. Witches are at the height of power at this time, which lasts approximately 4 hours from 12pm - 4am. Given that mana is plentiful during these hours, it is intuitive to think that rapid condensation would be possible, allowing for an industry boom never dreamed of by society. Sadly, this isn't the case. Although mana has increased, it is much slower to manipulate, limiting the number of spells that witches can perform. It is also much more difficult to turn into liquid form, making it almost impossible for any but the highest grade machines.

How can the fact of it being more plentiful make it much more difficult to use?

Comment: It looks like you're wanting us to make up some magibabble for you. If that's the case then literally every vaguely coherent magibabble is an equally valid answer.  Remember that the help center says "[questions with] many valid answers are probably too broad for this site."

Comment: Magic is always opinion based. limiting it things that are similar in reality to plentiful = more difficult is already a decent limiter.

Answer (score 1):

I like economy of postulates in designing such things.  The reason for it being (apparently) more plentiful and the reason why it doesn't work in the condensers should be linked with an underlying deeper cause.

At this time of day, the mana has a different nature; perhaps it is a different type overall, like a different element.  Or it could be less polymerized, or mixed (or not mixed) with an adjuncting compound.  This change in nature directly affects its ability to condense.  It *also* indirectly causes more of it to arrive, because it travels here uninterrupted as a vapor rather than forming clumps or condensing and re-evaporating on *things* along the way.

Answer (score 1):

**Mana follows gas laws.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_laws

PV = nRT ,
where
P is pressure
V is volume
n is the number of moles
R is the universal gas constant
T is temperature (K)

During the witching hour, /mana particles in the environment increase many fold/.  The stable volume but increase in pressure from increase in particle concentration produces an increase in temperature, which of course makes it more difficult to condense the mana into a liquid.

The higher pressure and more concentrated mana is more powerful and also more difficult to manipulate because of its pressure.  A liquid or gas under greater pressure exerts more force on an object used to contain it, and can distrupt or destroy that object.  So too mana under higher pressure, temperature and concentration tends to disrupt magical means of manipulation.

Comment: Is the uses of slash characters supposed to be _italic_ markdown?

Comment: @JDługosz  I used them to distinguish the text I quoted from the OP.  Probably I should have use quotation marks but I feel like those are to represent someone's spoken speech not written text.

Comment: I've used «Probably I should have use quotation marks», that is, French quotes, for this.  I don't think quotation marks are specific to medium.  In answer posts (rather than comments) we often use blockquotes to quote the OP.  Anyway, in this specific example it was not clear that this was a quotation, and the incorporation of quoted text into the grammar of a new sentence is kind of strange.